# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't load after grub

Tags: 12.10, grub2, mount

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Lenovo Thinkpad SL-510. The computer has been working for several weeks now with no problems.

Today when I turned the computer on I got a blank purple screen. Turning it on again (after a forced shutdown) I get to the grub screen. Selecting Ubuntu results in the following:

> mount: mounting /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root on /root failed: Invalid argument
>
> mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
>
> mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
>
> mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
>
> Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
>
> No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
>
> BusyBox v1.19.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.19.3-7ubuntu1.1) built-in shell (ash)
>
> Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
>
> (initramfs)

I ran the memory test from grub and it returned no errors, but I still get this message when trying to load Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Boot Repair. It may be helpful to you.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

[image: IMG:]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: After running Boot-Repair, the system started normally. Thank you Jai for the speedy answer!

Comment: You are most welcome, still i would suggest back-up your data if any..