# Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't boot after GRUB menu

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed on a Lenovo SL-510 laptop.

[Previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272597/ubuntu-12-10-doesnt-load-after-grub) I had a boot issue which resulted in a blank purple screen, that was solved using boot-repair to reinstall GRUB.

Right now it once again fails to boot. Selecting Ubuntu in the GRUB menu results in an empty screen with a command line cursor in the upper left corner.

Before this problem started, I got a scheduled updates notification, but it failed to install for some reason. This may or may not be relevant, but when the notification popped up, Transmission Bittorrent Client stopped downloading and wrote that the disk is write-protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we don't know did what state the update processes failed but as I understand (just guessing, not sure) there may be a "lack of permission" or "deadlock" problem which doesn't let boot process end up successfully.

On the other hand, that may be about the files required by linux kernel to load system and move_to_user_mode() or fork init(). If so; that probaby means your binaries are corrupted...

I hope you have a seperate partition for home directory but if not; here is my proposal:

- Start your system with a live OS
- Try to access your files
- Make a backup of them
- Reinstall your Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: I've just now started to back up files to an external drive, and again I encounter some permission issues: when I attempt to access folders that were copied to the PC from an external place (that same external drive which I use for backup purposes) I get a "You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of <foldername>" message, while folders that were created on the PC itself are accessed normally. Any solution for this? I would much rather not lose the info in those folders (they were updated since they were copied to the PC, obviously, or this would not be an issue)

Comment: Can you please try to chmod your folders you want to access / move recursively?

Comment: This works (as you might have understood I'm new to Ubuntu, I read how to this [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)), thanks for the tip. I'll reinstall and then see if the problem persists.

Comment: Glad to see it works! If you make a clean install; it wont :) By the way; you can apply my answer and help everyone here (including me)