# Boot fails to mount root partition

Tags: boot, init, initramfs

I recently installed Ubuntu successfully instead of Windows 7 and it was working very good. Suddenly while I was working, it restarted my computer and after I chose Ubuntu from grub it give me this error

```
mount: mounting/dev/disk/by-uuid/85a771fc-3df4-40e0-8e3d-b01d76019d5f on/root
failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting/dev on/root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting/sys on/root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting/proc on/root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested/sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init=bootarg.

BusyBox v1.21.1 (ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell(ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.10 doesn't load after grub](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272597/ubuntu-12-10-doesnt-load-after-grub)

Comment: if so what should i do @karel

Comment: Repair GRUB bootloader by following the instructions for getting, installing and using Boot-Repair at the [Ubuntu Documentation Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) wiki.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of a file system error.

Follow below steps:

1. Boot your system with the live Ubuntu DVD or else connect your hard disk to any working Ubuntu system.
2. Install the GParted tool
3. Open the Gparted tool
4. Select your hard disk
5. select first partition of your hard disk and right-click then select `check`
6. From top side click the green mark(apply)
7. select <kbd>OK</kbd> and it will check for errors and your issue will be resolved...

Comment: @MiHa: Could you please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/645488/revisions) and also edit the spelling and grammar for your edits in the future? **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Sure, I can do that.

Comment: when i opened Gparted it gave me this error @MiHa

Comment: Input/output error during read on/dev/sda@MiHa